# Im having trouble reading a binary archive

Tags: c++

I'm making my OOP final project and part of it is to make a couple of databases, I'm having trouble with this one.

I think my problem is with the reading of the binary file. I have a binary file called "datos.dat". I need to read that file, and put it on a vector. Libro being a struct formed by two chars variables, and three int variables.

```
struct registro_libro {
    char nombre[256];
    char genero[50];
    int id, precio, cantidad;
};

class Libreria {
private:
    
    string nombre_archivo;

    vector<Libro> arreglo;
    
public:
    Libreria(string a_nombre_archivo);
    
    
Libreria::Libreria(string a_nombre_archivo) {
        nombre_archivo = a_nombre_archivo;
        ifstream archivo(nombre_archivo.c_str(), ios::binary|ios::ate);
        if (archivo.is_open()) {
            int tamanio_archivo = archivo.tellg();
            int cantidad_libros = tamanio_archivo/sizeof(registro_libro);
            arreglo.resize(cantidad_libros);
            archivo.seekg(0,ios::beg);
            for (int i=0;i<cantidad_libros;i++)
                arreglo[i].LeerDesdeBinario(archivo);
            archivo.close();
        }
}
bool Libreria::Guardar() {
    std::ofstream archivo(nombre_archivo.c_str(),ios::binary|ios::trunc);
    if (!archivo.is_open()) return false;
    int cantidad_libros = CantidadDatos();
    for (int i=0;i<cantidad_libros;i++)
        arreglo[i].GuardarEnBinario(archivo);
    archivo.close();
    return true;


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    Libreria lib("datos.dat");
    for(int i=0;i<lib.CantidadDatos();i++) { 
        Libro &p = lib[i];
        cout <<i<<" "<< p.VerNombre()<<endl;
    }       
    int cual;
    while (true) {
        cout<<endl<<"Ingrese un nro de registro (-1 para salir): ";
        cin>>cual;
        if (cual==-1) break;
        if (cual>=lib.CantidadDatos()) {
            cout<<"Solo hay "<<lib.CantidadDatos()<<" registros"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        Libro &p=lib[cual];
        cout<<"Nombre: "<<p.VerNombre()<<endl;
        cout<<"Genero: "<<p.VerGenero()<<endl;
        cout<<"ID: "<<p.VerID()<<endl;
        cout<<"Precio: "<<p.VerPrecio()<<endl;
        cout<<"Cantidad: "<<p.VerCant()<<endl;
        
        
    }
    
    return 0;
```

The error that appears is main.cpp:10:17: error: no match for 'operator[]' in 'lib[i]' (operand types are 'Libreria' and 'int').

Same error in  Libro &p=lib[cual];

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I think now is readeable

Comment: I would suggest replacing your `char[]` members with `std::string` so copying etc work intuitively.

Comment: `lib` is an instance of `Libreria` class. It does not have a defined `operator[]` overload, therefore `lib[i]` is ill-formed. In order for "something[somethingelse]` to make any sense, in C++, "something" must have the `[]` operator defined. This is literally what the error message states. Which part of this error message is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your program:

1. Do not use char [] in struct, which is a high-risk operation.
2. The compilation fails because operator[] is missing in your librecia class.
3. It's best to unify your programming specifications, such as using camel case.